# Submitting 64 bit apps in Apple Store

Tags: ios7, 64-bit, xcode6

Currently my app user third party `SDKs` which does not support 64 bit.

I have removed `arm64` from my app build settings. Now my app runs fine in `apple 64 bit devices(like iPhone 5S)`.

I heard that apple will reject apps that won't support 64 bit.

`Is it mandatory to support 64 bit?.`

Answer (score 1):

If your app is already in the market, you still have time until June for 64-bit transition. If this will be your first submission, you won't be able to submit your app at all.

Because 64-bit devices have backward compatibility for 32-bit, your app would run fine on these devices, but Apple forces 64-bit support for better performance and to reduce fragmentation.

Your only choice would be to ask third party SDK developers to support 64-bit.